# Want secondary Y axis to start with0.8 and end to 1

Tags: reporting-services

I want my secondary Y axis to start with 0.8 and end with 1 with an interval of 0.02.
(i.e. 0.8,0.82,0.84,............1).What values I have to set in Secondary Y axis properties??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey I myself got the answer of these question.. What I have done is.. Interval---> 0.02 Interval Type--->Number Labels Format--->0.00\ I hope this will help others.